# fitting "accumulate" data

Tags: curve-fitting

I am trying to find the best function to fit my data. I have an image where items fall inside a circular region. My x values represent the radius of a circle, as x increases, the number of items (y values) that fall into it increases. So, y values are accumulated until all of the items are included. After normalization, y always ends at 1.

A sample data looks like this:

What function should I use to get the best fit? Initially, I thought Poisson. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66110390/fitting-commutative-poisson-distribution-in-python-doesnt-seem-correct?noredirect=1#comment116891714_66110390) But it doesn't seem correct.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I proposed the function below. The explanation of the calculus with the OP's data is given as a previous answer in : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66110390/fitting-commutative-poisson-distribution-in-python-doesnt-seem-correct?noredirect=1#comment116891714_66110390

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another and even simpler function :

[image]